# What is going on with my ArrayStack here?

Tags: c++, stack

So I have been trying to implement an arrayStack but I seem to have issues popping more than 100 elements. My program just stops working when it hits hundred. It seems that there is an issue with the push and pop but don't quite understand what my problem is.

```
#ifndef _ARRAYSTACK_1_HPP_
#define _ARRAYSTACK_1_HPP_

#include <stddef.h>
#include "StackADT.h"
#define DEFAULT_SIZE 50

template<class T>
class ArrayStack_1 : public StackADT<T> {

private: 
T *arrayStack; 
int index;
int maxSize;

public:
// a constructor for the arrayStack that creates and arrayStack of a given size
ArrayStack_1(int size = DEFAULT_SIZE) {
    maxSize = size;
    index = 0;
    arrayStack = new T[size];
}

public:

// a constructor for the arrayStack that creates and arrayStack of a given size
ArrayStack_1(int size = DEFAULT_SIZE) {
    maxSize = size;
    index = 0;
    arrayStack = new T[size];
}

//a destructor that deletes the arrayStack
~ArrayStack_1() {
    delete[] arrayStack;
}

bool Empty() {
    return index==0;
}

void Push(T& item = 0) {
    if (index<maxSize) {
        arrayStack[index]= item;
        index+=1;
    }else {
        T* tempArrayStack = arrayStack; //making a copy of the array stack
        maxSize+=1;
        arrayStack = new T[maxSize];

        for (int i=0; i<maxSize; i++){
            arrayStack[i]=tempArrayStack[i];
        }
        arrayStack[index]=item;
        index+=1;
        delete[] tempArrayStack;

    }
}

T Pop() {
        if(arrayStack[index]==0){
            return 0;
        }else {
            T element = arrayStack[index];
            index--;
            return element;
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual error message you got from running your code?

Comment: It ends before even it executes by saying array grow by 1.
http://imgur.com/rf6GQ6p

Comment: You need to stop editing your question as people fix your code for you. The answers no longer make sense because the question has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely all you should do is change `arrayStack[index]==0` to `index == 0` in your `Pop` function. Otherwise you risk accessing `arrayStack` with negative index which is undefined behaviour (likely a cause of your crash).

Also, when you are reallocating the stack, you should increase the stack size before the reallocation. I.e. swap these lines:

```
    T* arrayStack = new T[maxSize];
    maxSize+=1;
```

Furthermore, you don't assign the new value of `arrayStack` to your member variable - you define a new local variable in this code. Overall these lines should read:

```
    this->arrayStack = new T[++maxSize];
```

(Note, you don't have to write `this->arrayStack`, simple `arrayStack = ...` will do the job - it's just there for clarity of intent)
And don't forget to `delete tempArrayStack`, otherwise you leak memory.

**Edit**
These lines should also be swapped:

```
    index+=1;
    arrayStack[index]=item;
```

and again, you could use `++` - in this case the postfix version:

```
    arrayStack[index++] = item;
```

Learn about the difference for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1e3921c.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) versus [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy3d35h8.aspx)

Comment: Nope does not seem to be it.

Comment: Well, then look into the @John3136 answer. Nevertheless what I pointed out is a problem with your code as well.

Comment: To figure this out completely you need to provide the code that calls `ArrayStack_1` as well as definition of `DEFAULT_SIZE`

Comment: @dikshant I think I found the majority of bugs with your code now :)

Comment: @dikshant All the other guys' comments are also very valid. Especially reference-pushing. So read through them carefully.

Comment: So I edited the code in my question as directed in the comments any still the same issues. Any ideas?

Comment: @John3136 Good point. I'm in a good mood though and don't mind help people out. But yeah, it will be worthless for anyone else afterwards so not really in line with SO's guidelines

Comment: yes that index was the issue. I just figured it out as well. Thanks!

Comment: @John3136 Well, I tried to at least make it potentially useful by providing info about pre- and post-increments.

Comment: I meant to comment on the question, not your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You really should step through this code to see what it's doing.  I'm not sure how you would successfully make it to 100 iterations.

1. You need to pay more attention to when you are incrementing/decrementing.  Sometimes you increment before you set the item, and other times you increment after you set the item.
2. You're pushing a reference instead of a pointer (and your arrayStack should be a pointer list).
3. You should double the size when you hit an overflow condition to ensure you don't have to recreate the array on every push.
4. You have a substantial memory leak because you never delete arrayStack when you increase its size.
5. You are allocating a local variable and doing nothing with it.